# Navigate when website is not at root - angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have deployed the application in the virtual directory.

Now when I access the site as below:
www.abc.com/blog/admin/

It redirects to 
`www.abc.com/blog/admin/#/`

The site is working fine since I have below line in the app.js

`.when("/", { templateUrl: "app/dashboard/dashboardView.html" })`

However, when I load the page with www.abc.com/blog/admin it redirects to `www.abc.com/blog/admin#/` and throws 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to define what to do when route is "" i.e. add

```
.when("", { templateUrl: "app/dashboard/dashboardView.html" })
```

Or

.when("", "/")

Answer (score 0):

Make a hardcore change as below in your application

```
Replace("admin#","admin/#")
```

in case this is also not working you can refer below link, it is representing the same issue as you are facing.

https://github.com/rxtur/BlogEngine.NET/issues/167#issuecomment-372957515

Comment: Is there any alternate? because hard coding it for as many users is not a way to go